# I want to start Qt development - what basic knowledge in C++ and OS do I have to own?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm going to learn Qt and I just want to know what parts of C++, OO design and other things I must have background in? Templates, RAII, Patterns, ....?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QT is no different from any other platform or library you can use. To use it properly you only need to know the basics of C++ and how to compile and build your code.

[This tutorial](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/tutorial.html) takes you through the basics of building a QT application.

Of course like any other programming endeavor, the more you know about the language and tools you're using, the better.

Comment: the tutorial link does not show anything.

Answer (score 1):

The book ["Foundations of Qt development"](http://apress.com/book/view/1590598318) is the best resource IMHO. It is written by author of very good Qt3 tutorial - Johan Thelin. At first this book was also a free tutorial but became a book.

You can get both printed book and/or PDF.

Also might want to peek on [this question on best IDE for Qt4 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420065/best-crossplatform-c-qt4-development-environment).

Answer (score 1):

I think Linux/Unix with KDE GUI is one of the best choice for learning qt because you can be assured that qt library and c++ compiler is already installed. If your budget is limited,  the excellent Qt doc is more than enough to get you through the basic. It's easier to type *assistant* in your linux box to see the qt doc rather than online. 

In additon, you can browse/edit the code of many qt-based open source project to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading the book [C++ GUI Programming with Qt4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160).

It covers almost all features of Qt, is easy to read for a beginner, and also includes an introduction to C++ and Java, explaining the basic concepts required for developing with Qt.

I really enjoyed this book.

Answer (score 0):

I remember of Kylix (from Borlard aka CodeGear aka Embarcadero) that used Qt to develop GUI's for Linux. You can read an article here:
http://dn.codegear.com/article/29706

Unfortunatelly, Kylix was discontinued long time ago... but you can try the luck here:
http://support.codegear.com/forums/directory/kylix

Another good point to read is using Qt on eclipse:
http://www.qtsoftware.com/developer/eclipse-integration

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you know Python you could use [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro), it's as powerful as the C++ Qt but Python is easier than C++.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the book you should start using/reading.

[Qt Book](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/advanced-qt-programming-mark-summerfield/1100836028?cm_mmc=googlepla-_-textbook_notinstock_26to75_pt99-_-q000000633-_-9780321635907&ean=9780321635907&isbn=9780321635907&r=1)

Plus, you need fundamental understanding of Pointers, and class.