# Best C++ development environment in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ide

I have some experience with Eclipse and Qt creator and am somewhat disappointed in their debuggers, less so in their editors.  On Windows, I like Visual Studio for debugging and SlickEdit for editing (SE is also available on Linux).  Is there an IDE that is somehow better than the two mentioned?

Comment: Hard to believe, I know, but this has been asked here before.

Comment: Not to mention a well-configured well-customized emacs owns every IDE in existence.

Comment: Might want to peek at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420065/best-crossplatform-c-qt4-development-environment

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ IDE for Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I definitely recommend Eclipse and the CDT plugin. Emacs would be my preferred choice if you only need a good editor and not a full IDE.

I use Eclipse almost every day on Linux, mostly for C++ programming these days. The CDT plugin is really good because it is very well integrated with the g++ compiler and the gdb debugger. On top of that, the really strong feature of CDT is the code indexer - i.e. what Microsoft calls "intellisense" for Visual Studio. The CDT Indexer is so sophisticated it is almost like a compiler, in that it really understands your code as you type it. Very often it allows me to find errors even **before** I build my project. Also Eclipse can handle very large source trees, especially if you run it with a 64-bit JVM.

Eclipse is a great IDE with a lot of users, and if you don't know any other IDE you may want to start with it. Because it supports many languages and has so many tools, even if you switch to another project with different technologies you can still keep your IDE. So you only need to learn one tool (the same can be said for Emacs).

Answer (score 2):

Try [Eclipse CDT](http://eclipse.org/cdt/) or [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Emacs + [Emacs Code Browser](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) + g++(from gcc). [GCCSense](http://cx4a.org/software/gccsense/) in also pretty cool.

This is a lightweight, slick and extremely powerful environment. Not everybody like Emacs though. NetBeans is a good alternative for people accustomed to traditional IDEs.

Comment: I will second that.
GDB integration with emacs is excellent, not to mention extremely powerful scripting using elisp.
Also, take a look at cedet, which is sort of like Visual Studio environment

Comment: ECB uses cedet internally and add a few more bell and whistles :-) cscope for Emacs is a welcome addition to the mix as well

Answer (score 1):

I used [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) and it works flawlessly and it's great if you come from Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: The last Code::Blocks release was more than 2 years ago. I don't think that it's active developed any longer.

Comment: Code completion has never worked well for me. Maybe it's better in more recent "nightly" builds.

Answer (score 0):

[KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) 4 (kde-4.4 branch), built in cmake support, git, subversion, addon to add php support.

Answer (score 0):

nano (with syntax highlighting) + make + gcc + gdb + valgrind

Who needs anything else? ;)

Comment: Nano? O.o How about vim, emacs, geany, or pretty much *anything else*?

Comment: which syntax highlighting rules do you use?  The default ones have this annoying feature that they sometimes try to color a template as if it were the name of a header file.

Answer (score 0):

Geany, QT Creator, or Eclipse CDT.
If you don't need a full IDE learn emacs, it's not only an editor, but a full desktop environment, browser, terminal, and more, on its own.